# MySql how to speed-up working query with window functions

Tags: mysql, window-functions, cross-join, cursors

EDIT: Actually, main problem is the last update setting  A.last_52w_high_age_brutto_days (see below). Is it possible to opzimize this update or to integrate somehow in CURSOR update? Thank you.

---

I have a table with Stock Market daily prices.

Table Structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `cind_stocks_daily_rates` (
  `symbol` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  `p_date` int unsigned NOT NULL,
  `open_price` decimal(9,4) NOT NULL,
  `high_price` decimal(9,4) NOT NULL,
  `low_price` decimal(9,4) NOT NULL,
  `close_price` decimal(9,4) NOT NULL,
  `price_52w_low` decimal(9,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price_52w_high` decimal(9,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_52w_high_age_brutto_days` int unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`symbol`,`p_date `)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

INSERT Statement:

```
INSERT INTO cind_stocks_daily_rates (symbol, datum, open_price, high_price, low_price, close_price, price_52w_low, price_52w_high, last_52w_high_age_brutto_days)
VALUES
('DELL', 20210616, 150, 152, 149, 151, 149, 152, 0),
('INTZ', 20210616, 250, 252, 249, 251, 249, 252, 0),
('MSFT', 20210616, 350, 352, 349, 351, 349, 352, 0),
('NTNX', 20210616, 452, 452, 449, 451, 449, 452, 0),
('DELL', 20210617, 148, 151, 147, 150, 147, 152, 1),
('INTZ', 20210617, 251, 254, 250, 252, 249, 254, 0),
('MSFT', 20210617, 346, 349, 345, 347, 345, 352, 1),
('NTNX', 20210617, 450, 454, 450, 453, 449, 454, 0),
('DELL', 20210618, 146, 147, 144, 145, NULL, NULL, NULL),
('INTZ', 20210618, 254, 256, 253, 255, NULL, NULL, NULL),
('MSFT', 20210618, 349, 351, 349, 350, NULL, NULL, NULL),
('NTNX', 20210618, 453, 456, 452, 454, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Desired result:

```
symbol  datum   open_price  high_price  low_price   close_price price_52w_low   price_52w_high  last_52w_high_age_brutto_days
DELL    20210616    150 152 149 151 149 152 0
INTZ    20210616    250 252 249 251 249 252 0
MSFT    20210616    350 352 349 351 349 352 0
NTNX    20210616    452 452 449 451 449 452 0
DELL    20210617    148 151 147 150 147 152 1
INTZ    20210617    251 254 250 252 249 254 0
MSFT    20210617    346 349 345 347 345 352 1
NTNX    20210617    450 454 450 453 449 454 0
DELL    20210618    146 147 144 145 144 152 2
INTZ    20210618    254 256 253 255 249 256 0
MSFT    20210618    349 351 349 350 345 352 2
NTNX    20210618    453 456 452 454 449 456 0
```

After I have filled the table with prices/rates for a given day I want to calculate the high & low rates for a last 52 Weeks– as well as duration in days between day with last 52 Weeks high price and a value of date column.

I create a cursor:

```
SELECT distinct symbol FROM cind_stocks_daily_rates
WHERE  price_52w_low IS NULL OR price_52w_high IS NULL;
```

And loop the symbols through the Cursor (curr_symbol):

```
UPDATE cind_stocks_daily_rates AS A
CROSS JOIN
(SELECT AA.p_date, AA.symbol,
Min(AA.low_price) OVER (ORDER BY AA.p_date ROWS BETWEEN 260 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS low_price_52w,
Max(AA.high_price) OVER (ORDER BY AA.p_date ROWS BETWEEN 260 PRECEDING AND 
CURRENT ROW) AS high_price_52w
FROM cind_stocks_daily_rates AA
WHERE AA.symbol = curr_symbol
ORDER BY AA.p_date) as B ON B.symbol = A.symbol AND B.p_date = A.p_date
SET A.price_52w_low = B.low_price_52w,
A.price_52w_high = B.high_price_52w,
WHERE  A.price_52w_low IS NULL OR A.price_52w_high IS NULL;
```

After cursor loop I have another update to determine how old is current 52 Weeks High price from today:

EDIT: Actually, following update is my main problem (and only problem). Duration approx. +/- 10 minutes. END_OF_EDIT

```
UPDATE cind_stocks_daily_rates AS A
CROSS JOIN
 (SELECT AA.p_date, AA.symbol,
DATEDIFF(STR_TO_DATE(AA.p_date, "%Y %m %d"),STR_TO_DATE(
    (SELECT CCC.p_date
    FROM cind_stocks_daily_rates CCC
    WHERE CCC.symbol = AA.symbol AND CCC.p_date <= AA.p_date AND CCC.high_price = AA.price_52w_high ORDER BY CCC.p_date DESC LIMIT 1)
    , "%Y %m %d")) AS last_high_Date
    FROM cind_stocks_daily_rates AA) as B ON B.symbol = A.symbol AND B.p_date = A.p_date
        SET A.last_52w_high_age_brutto_days = B.last_high_Date
WHERE A.last_52w_high_age_brutto_days IS NULL;
```

It works everything as wanted without errors, just it takes too much time. Is it possible to speed it up? Is it possible to set the field “last_52w_high_age_brutto_days” together within cursor (without second update after cursor loop)? Please any ideas to make the queries faster?

Comment: How much time is too much?

Comment: Why CROss JOIN?

Comment: Besidaes all the STR_:TO_DATE must time an you do it multiple times, why not save them proper mysql style and get rid of all taht

Comment: [Edit] the question and complete the [example], i.e. provide `INSERT` statements for sample data (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format.

Comment: "And loop ... through the Cursor" -- That's the first thing you want to get rid of. RDBMS excel at set based operations but suck when it comes to looping cursors.

Comment: I guess you don't have any BRK.A.  It would need `DECIMAL(10,4)`, which, by the way, takes 5 bytes, just as (9,4) does.

Comment: Isn't "260" incorrect due to holidays?

Comment: Are you computing the min/max only from "today"?  And not retrofitting unset values from earlier days?

Comment: @Strawberry - The table has 300k records with approx 450 stocks and last 2,5 years. Everyday there are new 450 Stock-records to be computed. This lasts at least 15-20 minutes to be done on Intel Core i6 with 16 GB memory.

Comment: @nbk - because I don't have a better idea. I'm not saying it's a best solution, just asking here for a better one. Thanks.

Comment: Hm, that is a tiny data set. You're right; this should take seconds - and I agree that the 'cursor' should just be a join

Comment: @stickybit - I have done it. Excuse me if desired result tabular format is not as you expected, I've done my best.

Comment: @RickJames - no, it's without BRK.A .......... I didn't want to complicate it, therefore last 260 trading days.......... Your 3rd question: I'm computing it for every day, mostly daily.

Comment: @Strawberry  - I’m trying today to speed up my last UPDATE, not one within CURSOR but the one setting last_52w_high_age_brutto_days. That’s the biggest problem for me because this query need the most time to be ended. With JOIN (without CROSS) there is still several minutes needed for query, probably 10 seconds less but still multiple minutes needed. Do you see any possibility to compute this ‘last_52w_high_age_brutto_days’ field within cursor’s query where I use window-functions? Thanks.

Comment: What does `last_52w_high_age_brutto_days` mean?  (I can't tell from the query.)

Comment: @RickJames - last_52w_high_age_brutto_days is Integer Number of days between p_date and the date with current "52 Weeks High Price". Let's say highest price of last 52 Weeks was on 06/15, p_date is 06/27 -> last_52w_high_age_brutto_days should be then 12

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to avoid doing everything every day.

A big task is finding the 52-week highest price.  Let's see if there is a shortcut.

Maintain a separate table, one row per ticker, of the 52-week high and date of such.

If the date (for a given ticker) of the 52-week high is less than 52 weeks ago, then the price and date do not to be recomputed.

Then it is easy and fast to discover which, if any, tickers need their highs recomputed.  Update this table.  Then use this table to populate the table you are asking about; this `UPDATE...JOIN...` will be efficient.

Some potential problems --

- Non-trading days: I don't think, this messes up the queries at all; ignore it.
- Occasionally, most of the tickers will have their high exactly 52 weeks ago:  This will be rare, and, alas, slow.